# Global Navigation stored anywhere?

Tags: navigation

I'm creating global navigation menus for multiple sites. Each one is essentially the same, but translated from English into French, Dutch, German and Spanish, with some subtle changes (links added or removed depending on language).

I'm wondering if these are stored anywhere in an editable form, such as an XML file? It would make it much easier if I could create one, then copy its file and edit it in notepad with a new name/location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we do for this, is creating a new Navigation Datasource for this.
In our example we have a MSSQL database representing our navigation (with ofcourse a caching mechanism).
But you could use your own data storage with this custom navigation datasource...

Its to much info to just explain this here.
But you can use these links for information:

http://cosier.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/creating-a-custom-sharepoint-navigation-datasource/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms432695(v=office.12).aspx (=for quicklaunch, but it can be addapted for top nav)

http://blog.symprogress.com/2011/03/sharepoint2010-custom-navigation-provider-cross-sitecollection/

Comment: Thanks for the information, Frederik. It turned out, for me, to be quicker doing this by hand - though the information provided will certainly be useful for others too.

Comment: Almost everything can be done manual... It just depends how automized you want it to be.